# Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) : invalid 'envir' argument when using dbDisconnect() after dbCommit()

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc, instantclient, r-dbi

I am trying to update the oracle database through R by using this code:

```
cxn <- makeCxn(config)
    x <- try(res <- dbSendUpdate(cxn, query))
   dbCommit(cxn)
    dbDisconnect(cxn)
```

Then I got the error:

```
Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) :    invalid 'envir' argument
```

I am using the RJDBC package and I connect to the database by instant Client.

A sample config is

```
config<- list(

      drv = JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "<path>"),

  user = "username",
  password = "password",
  url = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
)
```

My OS is windows 7.

Anyone can help? In a hurry!

Thanks

Comment: I install instant client basic, instant client odbc, instant client jdbc in the same package.

Comment: a sample query:DECLARE xxx
         BEGIN
   INSERT INTO  ana_metrics (name, id) 
   , 
        
  VALUES ( 'af',xxxx );
  COMMIT; 
  END;